# How do I encode a list of tuples in a POST?

Tags: http, post

I want to pass a list of tuples in a POST

e.g.

```
key_value_pairs = [(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)]
```

I know that you can send a record in POST like this :

```
address[name] = "123 Fake Street"
address[city] = "Nowhereville"
```

and also you can send a list like this

```
list[] = 1
list[] = 2
list[] = 3
```

But how do I send a list of records (tuples) in my first example?

Comment: What language are you using? Regarding the question itself, if you don't have any native structure serialisation available, you can always use json (and correct the type from lists to tuples later - you know where to expect them).

Comment: You can't really send a record in a POST. All POST does is send a bunch of key-value pairs of strings. Keys can be multivalued which lets you kinda sorta send a list, but you certainly don't have to end the key name in `[]` for that. This question doesn't really make much sense without an implementation language / framework, and its answer follows from false premises and likely doesn't make sense either.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it - it is pretty language agnostic.

If you want to send a list of tuples e.g.

```
 [(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)]
```

You can do this :

```
 x = [1,3,5]
 y = [2,4,6]
```

then you can reconstruct them

```
 for each x.index as i
   tuples[] = (x.i, y.i)
```

You could also pass the tuples in a serialized format, but I just feel safer the less serialization takes place.

Comment: What does `x = [1, 3, 5]` even mean?! Are you sending a single `x` key with the value `[1, 3, 5]`? Or are you sending three `x` (or `x[]`) keys? An either way, *both* of those count as doing serialisation, at which point you might as well serialize to a well-known format that's as language-agnostic as your half-baked solution that requires both sides to recognize a proprietary ad-hoc structure to the request.

Comment: Notwithstanding the fact that the very notion of "list of tuples" isn't language-agnostic to begin with.